# How to display filtered data in serializer's source attribute Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've added an additional action to my ModelViewSet as below. I have a manager function which it's name is `related_interests` and it should filter the `user interests`. I put `source` attribute to my serializer to get filtered interests however, I'm getting all of them in my response.

```
class MyModelViewSet(
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin
):
    """ModelViewSet with create, list, retrieve and custom_action operations"""

    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MyModelSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def custom_action(self, request):
       queryset = MyModel.objects.related_interests()
       serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
       return responses.http_ok_with_dict(serializer.data)
```

And here is my serializer;

```
class UserWithInterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    licenses = InterestSerializer(read_only=True, source="interest_set", many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserWithInterestSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ["user"]
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: i'm asking a dumb question, but have you tried to enter in debug mode and check if the request you send is actually entering in your custom manager?

Comment: yes, my custom manager works properly.

Comment: Instead of using ```Mymodel.objects.all()``` did you tried doing filter on queryset ```MyModel.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)``` by overriding ```def get_queryset(self)``` for that particular action.